# List attributes from WooCommerce products in their grouped name attributes

Tags: php, woocommerce, product-variations

I use `wc_get_products($args)` to get list of products with certain argument. Then I use `wc_get_product` and `get_available_variations` to access the list of product variable detail which contain attributes. How can I list group of each attributes separately like image below?

[image: Image describing the issue]

According to the image, there are 3 variables. In loop of 3 I use `get_term_by` to get the arrays of attributes, but the are three data in each array:

- array_1 (blue, green, red) its OK
- array_2 (large, large, large) my problem is here

Comment: Is large size only available for this product? Like 0 :[blue=> large], 1: [green=> large], etc.